# Django Middleware breaking form submission?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-middleware

When I add middleware, the forms on the page with `TemplateResponse` stop working: submission causes loading for several minutes, and then results in a load-balancer error.

The `form`, `process_img` method, and `bot` view all work exactly as expected when the middleware isn't defined in `settings.py`.

The code:

In settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'polls.views.ExampleMiddleware'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'polls.views.ExampleMiddleware'
]
```

Middleware definition in views.py:

```
class ExampleMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        if 'right' in request.POST:
            response.context_data['response'] = 'Sweet, thanks!'
        elif 'wrong' in request.POST:
            response.context_data['response'] = 'Awww, sorry'
        return response
```

Relevant view in `views.py`:

```
def bot(request):
    img_form = ImageUploadForm()
    context = {'img_form':img_form}
    if request.method=='POST':
        img_form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if img_form.is_valid():
            myfile = request.FILES['image']
            context = process_img(myfile)
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'polls/bot.html',context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'polls/bot.html',context)
```

Details: Python 3.5, Django 1.11, hosting on Python anywhere.

What's breaking the form submission and how do I fix it?

Edit: Sever log says

> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 Sun Nov  5 16:56:25 2017 - *** HARAKIRI ON WORKER
>   2 (pid: 15659, try: 1) ***
>
> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 Sun Nov  5 16:56:25 2017 - HARAKIRI !!! worker 2
>   status !!!
>
> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 Sun Nov  5 16:56:25 2017 - HARAKIRI [core 0]
>   10.0.0.222 - POST / since 1509900084
>
> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 Sun Nov  5 16:56:25 2017 - HARAKIRI !!! end of
>   worker 2 status !!!
>
> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 15659) died, killed by
>   signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
>
> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 20420)
>
> 2017-11-05 16:56:26 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 2

Comment: What's the load balancer error?

Comment: Not sure but shouldn't you override __init__ properly? def __init__...... self.get_response = ... super(ExampleMiddleware,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)?

Comment: @markwalker_ it just says Error code: 504-loadbalancer. I've edited to include what the server log says.

Comment: Note that `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is the old setting for Django <= 1.9. You shouldn't set it as well as `MIDDLEWARE`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your settings.py you forgot to put comma after "'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'".

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'polls.views.ExampleMiddleware'
]
```

Comment: good catch, but just a typo on my end here--not related to the problem